# Unable to Add Button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am unable to add button on UIView. I have UIView In which I want to add UIButton.
 Here is my code which I am trying to implement.

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
            path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
            [path setLineWidth:1.0];


            _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [_button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            _button.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            _button.frame =CGRectMake(50, 130, 100, 100);
            _button.backgroundColor =[ UIColor redColor];
            [_button addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(buttonClicked)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self addSubview:_button];

   }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: IT has no View Did Load method it has UIView Subclass

Comment: @priyankagautam does it exists or your getting errors in your project

Comment: Not any error . they not show any button on ui

Comment: @priyankagautam is your view getting displayed?

Comment: where you are allocating this view? If I create an instance and allocate it in view did load of the controller on which I have to show this view , i can see the view as well as button.

Comment: @Rumin Yes My view is dispayed but not adding Button

Comment: @Nayan I am actually make an App of Editing in which we make writing . I am adding on another ViewController as SubView. But problem is that if i want to add on view did Load. They work fine no doubt. But problem is that we perform action in my Uiview class

Comment: What I would like to suggest is to allocate this view's instance somewhere and then call [self.view addSubView:thisView]. This will simply work if I got your problem

Comment: How did you define the button property? If it's defined as weak, the button will be deleted immediately after creation and never be added to the view. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is being added to the view. I just tried with your code line by line and I could see it. I think problem is in your `UIView` frame. Probably you are not seeing it because it is crossing the boundary of your super `UIView`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning to __button, make a local UIButton object and work with it. After the local button has been added to the view, assign it to _button.